# PROLOG: process of inference, why returns false

Tags: prolog, inference

I have a definition of `conc`:

```
conc([], L2, L2).
conc([X1|R1], L2, [X1|RN]) :-
   conc(R1, L2, RN).
```

I don't understand why `conc([X | green], Y, [red, green, blue]).` returns `false` rather than

```
X = [red],
Y = [blue]
```

What is the process of inference here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know Prolog. The rest of this answer is an edumacated guess.

Your proposed solution of `X = [red]` doesn't make sense because that would make `X` a one-element list. Let's assume

```
X = red
```

instead.

That would give us

```
conc([red | green], [blue], [red, green, blue]).
```

With the second equation of `conc` that turns into

```
conc(R1, L2, RN).
% with:
% X1 = red
% R1 = green
% L2 = [blue]
% [X1|RN] = [red, green, blue]
% i.e. X1 = red
%      RN = [green, blue]
```

I.e.

```
conc(green, [blue], [green, blue]).
```

And now we're stuck because none of your `conc` rules applies to `green`.

The problem is `[X | green]` because `green` is not the tail of a list.

Did you mean `[X, green]` instead?

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog list notation, the `|` separates the elements enumerated at its left from a **list** of the remaining elements at its right. The issue is in your query. Instead of `[X | green]` you need to write either `[X | [green]]` or `[X,green]`. With one of these fixes, you get correct answer. E.g.

```
?- conc([X | [green]], Y, [red, green, blue]).
X = red,
Y = [blue].
```